# Primes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes, lazy-evaluation

I'm learning Haskell, and I've tried to generate an infinite list of primes, but I can't understand what my function is doing wrong.

The function:

```
prime = 2:3:filter (\x -> all (\y -> (mod x y) > 0) (init prime)) [5..]
```

I think it's the `init prime`, but the strange thing is that even if I set an upper bound to the range (`5..10` for example), the function loops forever and never gets any result for `prime !! 2`

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you're trying to filter a list to keep only those elements that are not divisible by any element of `init prime`. In order to check that for every element of `init prime`, Haskell needs to figure out all the elements (except the "last one") of `prime`. Now can you see the problem? Lazy evaluation doesn't help you when you need the full data structure to compute an intermediate result.

Comment: You can rescue your idea by replacing `(init prime)` with `(takeWhile (\z -> z * z <= x) prime)` as every non-prime number has a prime factor not greater than its square root.

Comment: I see, but then: is there another way to use the partial result to calculate the next element of the infinite list? I find it confusing that it's not an error, because it's obviously wrong.

Comment: Your call to `init primes` suggest you think each iteration will only see the list as constructed up to this point.  If that is your belief then it is wrong, the `primes` list simply isn't fully computed.  Avoid using the portion of the list you're generating such as is done in ShreevatsaR's comment.

Comment: Yes, that works of course, thanks, I just wanted to understand if it's possible to extend an infinite list recursively by using a part of the list itself for calculating the next elements.

Comment: It absolutely is; that's what @ShreevatsaR's comment recommends. The only reason yours doesn't work is that the part of the infinite list used (`init`) overlaps with the part of the list that is being produced. If you prevent that overlap by using an appropriate `takeWhile`, no problems.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. I tried, but inits is just as undefined as init in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, for one let's look at what `init` does for a finite list:

```
init [1] == []
init [1,2] == [1]
init [1,2,3] == [1,2]
```

ok, so it gives us all but the last element of the list.

So what's `init primes`? Well, `prime` without the last element. Hopefully if we implemented `prime` correctly it shouldn't *have* a last element (because there are infinitely many primes!), but more importantly we don't quite need to care yet because we don't have the full list for now anyway - we only care about the first couple of elements after all, so *for us* it's pretty much the same as just `prime` itself.

Now, looking at `all`: What does this do? Well, it takes a list and a predicate and tells us if all the elements of the list satisfy the predicate:

```
all (<5) [1..4] == True
all even [1..4] == False
```

it even works with infinite lists!

```
all (<5) [1..] == False
```

so what's going on here? Well, here's the thing: It does work with infinite lists... but only if we can actually evaluate the list up to the first element of the list that violates the predicate! Let's see if this holds true here:

```
all (\y -> (mod 5 y) > 0) (init prime)
```

so to find out if `5` is a prime number, we'd have to check if there's a number in prime minus the last element of prime that divides it. Let's see if we can do that.

Now let's look at the definition of prime, we get

```
all (\y -> (mod 5 y) > 0) (2:3:filter (\x -> all (\y -> (mod x y) > 0) (init prime)) [5..])
```

So to determine whether 5 is a prime number, we only have to check if it's:

1. divisible by 2 - it's not, let's continue
2. divisible by 3 - still no
3. divisible by ...? Well, we're in the process of checking what the 3rd prime is so we don't know yet...

and there's the crux of the problem. With this logic, to determine the third prime number you need to know the third prime number! Of course logically, we actually *don't* want to check this at all, rather we only need to check if any of the *smaller* prime numbers are divisors of the current candidate.

So how do we go about doing that? Well, we'll have to change our logic unfortunately. One thing we can do is try to remember how many primes we already have, and only take as many as we need for our comparison:

```
prime = 2 : 3 : morePrimes 2 [5..]
  morePrimes n (x:xs)
    | all (\y -> mod x y > 0) (take n prime) = x : morePrimes (n+1) xs
    | otherwise                              = morePrimes n xs
```

so how does this work? Well, it basically does what we were just talking about: We remember how many primes we already have (starting at `2` because we know we have at least `[2,3]` in `n`. We then check if our next prime is divisible by any of the of `n` primes we already know by using `take n`, and if it is we know it's our next prime and we need to increment `n` - otherwise we just carry on.

There's also the more well known form inspired by (although not quite the same as) the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
prime = sieve [2..] where
  sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve (filter (\x -> mod x p > 0) xs)
```

so how does this work? Well, again with a similar idea: We know that the next prime number needs to be non-divisible by any previous prime number. So what do we do? Well, starting at `2` we know that the first element in the list is a prime number. We then throw away every number divisible by that prime number using `filter`. And afterwards, the next item in the list is going to be a prime number again (because we didn't throw it away), so we can repeat the process.

Neither of these are one liners like the one you were hoping for though.

Comment: Two objections: `init` isn't applied ever to `[5..]`, so the explanation of what `init [5..]` does seems irrelevant; and we absolutely have *not* already established that `prime` is an infinite list (indeed, it *isn't* an infinite list, so we certainly can't establish that it is).

Comment: @DanielWagner Argh, right on both counts. I've managed to out do myself with this one, I don't think I can salvage this answer

Comment: @Cubic I believe in you!

Comment: @Cubic Without the removal of `init`, your argument essentially stills works, but becomes a bit more complicated. `let prime_rest = filter f [5..]` (with appropriate `f`); then you can apply your reasoning to deduce that `prime_rest = case f 5 of { True -> 5 : prime_rest1; False -> prime_rest1 } where prime_rest1 = filter f [6..]` (with some rewriting of the definition of filter). But to evaluate `f 5` you must first determine if `prime_rest` is `[]` or `_:_` (by the definiton of `f` and `init`); and `prime_rest` is the very expression you're currently evaluating.

Comment: @Cubic In other words, you can rewrite `prime_rest` to `case prime_rest of { [] -> ..; [x] -> ..; (x:xs) -> .. }` with the outermost `case` statement being the definition of `init`.

Comment: lotsa one-liners [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#One-liners). :)

Answer (score 1):

If the code in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56119444/849891) is restructured under the identity

```
[take n primes | n <- [0..]]  ==  inits primes
```

eventually we get

```
import Data.List
              -- [ ([], 2), ([2], 3), ([2,3], 5), ... ]
primes = 2 : [ c | (ps, p) <- zip (inits primes) primes,  
                   c <- take 1 [c | c <- [p+1..], 
                                    and [mod c p > 0 | p <- ps]]]
```

Further improving it algorithmically, it becomes

```
primes = 2 : [ c | (ps, r:q:_) <- zip (inits primes)                  -- [] [3,4,...]
                                      (tails $ 3 : map (^2) primes),  -- [2] [4,9,...]
                   c <- [r..q-1], and [mod c p > 0 | p <- ps]]        -- [2,3] [9,25,...]
```